# JMF, Java Mídia Framework, há um substituto?

Tags: java, streaming, jmf

Há alguns anos, algo em torno de 10 anos, iniciei um projeto de levantamento de dados rodoviários, este projeto estava sendo feito em Java e utilizava o JMF, um framework para lidar com diversos tipos de mídias em especial streaming de vídeo e áudio, eu comecei a fazer adaptações para gerar gráficos com base em odômetros, barômetros, termômetros e GPS por exemplo além de outros streams, mas vejo hoje ao rever o projeto que tal framework está abandonado e parece não haver nada de novo para as novas versões do Java.

Então a fica as dúvidas?

- como está este framework para as versões mais atuais do Java?
- há algum substituto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> como está este framework para as versões mais atuais do Java?

Bem, JMF é a API padrão (Java SE), última atualização (manutenção) pode ser vista no [JSR-920 - JMF 2.1.1 (ano 2002)](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=920), sendo a primeira a [JSR-908 - JMF 2.0 (ano 2000)](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=908).

> há algum substituto?

Alguns projetos,

- https://github.com/caprica/vlcj (projeto bem ativo, embarca o VLC e permite refinar bem as configurações)
- https://github.com/gstreamer-java
- https://github.com/Red5/red5-client
- http://fmj-sf.net/index.php

Comment: Reginaldo me desculpe demora, bem, entendi sua resposta, mas julgo que algumas edições são necessárias, estarei fazendo caso não concorde não se sinta constrangido em reverter.

Comment: @Delfino obrigado pelos ajustes.